# How do you parse the last sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The original sentence:

> Above all the car changes everything: rising incomes and rising
>   populations can make urban car density increase by something like four
>   and five per cent in a decade; traffic flows rise to fill whatever
>   scale of highways **are** provided for them.

My question is on the last sentence. It's my understanding that a noun (phrase) is expected as the object of the verb "fill." But it is a sentence in the book. It would be easier for me to comprehend the sentences without "are."

> Above all the car changes everything: rising incomes and rising
>   populations can make urban car density increase by something like four
>   and five per cent in a decade; traffic flows rise to fill whatever
>   scale of highways provided for them.

Or "fill" is used as an intransitive verb here as below, which means "fill full":

> Above all the car changes everything: rising incomes and rising
>   populations can make urban car density increase by something like four
>   and five per cent in a decade; **whatever scale of highways are provided for them, traffic flows rise to fill**.

Well, on the second thought, I feel "fill" can be followed by a complete sentence as its object, which means the original text is perfectly fine. But I would like to keep the question on to get some feedback.

Comment: "Whatever scale of highways are provided for them" **is** a noun phrase. What else could it be?

Comment: @BillJ, Bill, thanks. I know many transitive verbs can use both a noun phrase and a that-clause as the object. But some cannot. For instance, want, allow, expect, or ask are better not to be followed by a that-clause. But transitive verbs are always safe to have a noun (phrase) as the object. I was just not sure about 'fill' to be followed by a sentence when I asked the question.

Comment: "Whatever" is a determinative, serving as determiner in the NP "scale of highways". The NP "whatever scale of highways [(that) are provided for them]"  contains the bracketed 'fused' relative clause -- note the possibility of including "that".

Comment: There *is* only one sentence. What you're talking about is the clause that follow the semicolon.